# Вводится текст, за которым следует точка. В алфавитном порядке напечатать (по разу) все строчные русские буквы, входящие в этот текст

Tags: c, массивы, строки

Дали задание, но проблема - не могу найти в массиве строчные символы.

Задание:

> Вводится текст, за которым следует точка. В алфавитном порядке напечатать (по разу) все строчные русские буквы, входящие в этот текст.

Мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251 > nul");
    char result[80] = {""};
    char str[80] = {""};
    printf("Input String\n");
    gets(str);

    for(int i = 0; i < 80; i++){
        char d = str[i];
        int t = d;
        if(d >= 0xA0 && d<= 0xEF){// что писать для сравнения не знаю уже

            strcat(result,str[i]);
        }
    }
    puts(result);


}
```

Comment: `if(d >= 0xA0 && d<= 0xEF)` - может, тут `t` сравнивать?

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str)-1; i++){ // gets вводит и символ '\n'
        if(islower(str[i])){// Прописной символ?
            // strcat(result,str[i]); Нелья соединять СТРОКУ и СИМВОЛ
            result[strlen(result)] = str[i]; // Прицепляем символ
            result[strlen(result)+1] = '\0';   // И терминатор строки
        }
    }
```